# OrderBy its not wokring on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, eloquent, laravel-7

i have a problem when doing "orderBy" name product. here are my codes

```php
$resume =  Transaction::with(['product' => function ($q) {
    $q->orderBy('name_product','ASC');
}])
->where('status', 'keluar')
->where('status', 'masuk')
->get();
```

but my code its not working... here is the output
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riyM7.png)

Comment: Are you trying to sort the transitions by it's related product name?

Comment: Yes, that is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the collection to sort instead. It allows for sorting based on a nested property.

```php
$resume =  Transaction::with('product')
->where('status', 'keluar')
->where('status', 'masuk')
->get()
->sortBy('product.name_product')
->values();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are applying condition to `product`, not in `transaction`.

I have another suggestion use `whereHas`.

```php
Transaction::whereHas('product', function($query) {
  $query->->orderBy('name_product','ASC');
})->where('status', 'keluar')
->where('status', 'masuk')
->get();
```